# CGContext draw 45 degree line joint

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawpath

Is there any way to draw lines in CGContext which connected with each other with 45 degree angle, like this picture shows: [image]

Comment: No, you need to use two shapes/paths and fill them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to do it.  If there were, it would be one of the options you could pass to [`CGContextSetLineCap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetLineCap), but it only supports Butt, Round, and Square.

What you would need to do is write a function that takes two end points, a direction (so you know which side to make smaller), and a color.  Use this info to draw a filled-in trapezoid.